# How to get matching pairs with R's RecordLinkage package

Tags: r, record-linkage

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to test the R package RecordLinkage's compare function on a toy dataset

```
> test<-cbind(
+ a = c(1, 1, 1), 
+ b = c(2, 0, 2), 
+ c = c(1, 2, 1))
> 
> test
     a b c
[1,] 1 2 1
[2,] 1 0 2
[3,] 1 2 1
> 
> results <- compare.dedup(test)
> 
> results$pairs
  id1 id2 a b c is_match
1   1   2 1 0 0       NA
2   1   3 1 1 1       NA
3   2   3 1 0 0       NA
>
```

Records 1 and 3 clearly match but is_match is NA for all three pairs.

Comment: The 'is_match' would be specified in the original data to show that a pair actually match. The 'RecordLinkage' package is primarily designed to test linkage algorithms and this column allows evaluating algorithms on benchmark data.

Comment: Thanks Richard - I get it now. - But, if for example I enter head(RLdata500) I do not see an identity column - where is it?

Comment: For anyone, who stumbles accross this question like me: type "help(RLdata500)" in R. It explains that identity.RLdata500 is a separatly defined vector, that holds the unique ID's.

Answer (score 2):

because you forgot to use a identity index:

```
> compare.dedup(cbind(a=c(1,1,1), b=c(2,0,2), c=c(1,2,1)), identity=c(1,2,3))$pair
id1 id2 a b c is_match
1   1   2 1 0 0        0
2   1   3 1 1 1        0
3   2   3 1 0 0        0
```

Comment: But the identitly is optional - and also your example still doesn't indicate that records 1 and 3 are a match

Comment: Don't worry - I have worked this out - identity is for supervised training

Comment: @RossFarrelly how did you fix this? I have the same problem... `is_match` only results in `NAs`

Comment: Has anyone managed to resolve this? Am having the same issue where the is_match column all shows NA

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, who stumbles accross this question like me: type

```
help(RLdata500)
```

in R. It explains that identity.RLdata500 is a separatly defined vector, that holds the unique ID's.

I think, it is define separatly, because otherwise, the data would be used by some of the functions automatically, unless they would be explicitly told, to do not so...

To see, which rows are duplicates, type the following in R:

```
i=cbind(RLdata500,identity.RLdata500)
L = i[8] == 33
i[L,]
```

Comment: Please mind, that I am a beginner in R - so there might be a more elegant way, to show the duplicated data-records. (If someone knows a way, to olny show this rows of the combined matrix "i", I would like to hear about it.)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I have the possible solution for this answer This is due to identity parameter.

from the sample data, in Record Linkage package, I found that this vector `identity.RLdata500` carry information about the duplicate records of `RLdata500` out of 500 records 50 are duplicate records

```
length(unique(identity.RLdata500))
[1] 450
```

I found the similar column in my dataset and stored as a separate vector and passed the vector to the identity parameter

```
New_data_seq
118
118

New_data_seq <- R_New_data_zero$SEQ_NO 
abc <- compare.dedup (R_New_data_zero,identity = New_data_seq) 

BICODE ALCODE IS_T OID conc
 I      A     1    99   IA1
 I      A     1    99   IA1
abc$pairs[1:1, ]

id1 id2 BICODE ALCODE IS_T OID conc is_match
 1   2   1        1    1    1    1       1
```